# codigo para optimizar windows soy nuevo

Tags: vbscript, vbs

Soy nuevo, queria hacer un codigo para facilitarme el trabajo y ejecutar estas tareas. Pero falla diciendo se esperaba un final de instruccion.
No me odien, no cazo una y di lo mejor de mi. Pero estoy a punto de borrar este .vbs e irme a dormir despues de 3 horas peleando jaja

se les ocurre algo que pueda hacer para que funcione? o otras maneras de formular las acciones que quiero hacer?

Desde ya se agradece el espacio para esta consulta.
Me pide que añada mas detalles y no se que decir asi que bueno cualquier cosita me cuentan xd

```
    WScript.Echo "Creando carpeta de respaldo del registro..."
mkdir "C:\Backup REG"
WScript.Echo "Carpeta de respaldo del registro creada"

WScript.Echo "Realizando copia de seguridad del registro..."
reg export "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE" "C:\Backup REG\software.reg"
WScript.Echo "Copia de seguridad del registro realizada"

WScript.Echo "Ocultando botón de búsqueda en barra de tareas..."
reg add "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Search" /v "SearchboxTaskbarMode" /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f end
WScript.Echo "Botón de búsqueda en barra de tareas ocultado"

WScript.Echo "Desanclando Microsoft Store de la barra de tareas..."
Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
strTaskbarPath = objShell.SpecialFolders("Taskbar")
Set objLink = objShell.CreateShortcut(strTaskbarPath & "\Microsoft Store.lnk")
objLink.Delete
WScript.Echo "Microsoft Store desanclado de la barra de tareas"

Set objShell = Nothing
Set objLink = Nothing

WScript.Echo "Desactivando aplicaciones en segundo plano..."
reg add "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\BackgroundAccessApplications" /v "GlobalUserDisabled" /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f
reg add "HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\BackgroundAccessApplications" /v "GlobalUserDisabled" /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f
WScript.Echo "Aplicaciones en segundo plano desactivadas"

WScript.Echo "Desconectando noticias e intereses..."
reg add "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Search" /v "BingSearchEnabled" /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f
reg add "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Search" /v "CortanaConsent" /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f
reg add "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\Windows Search" /v "AllowCortana" /t REG_DW



WScript.Echo "Deshabilitando contenido recomendado..."
reg add "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\ContentDeliveryManager" /v "SubscribedContent-336547hewjtrwekjwerhjkwerhjkwerhjkrwehjkrwehjkrwehjkrwehjkrweh" /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f
WScript.Echo "Contenido recomendado deshabilitado"



WScript.Echo "Creando acceso directo para Outlook en la barra de tareas..."
Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
strTaskbarPath = objShell.SpecialFolders("Taskbar")
Set objLink = objShell.CreateShortcut(strTaskbarPath & "\Outlook.lnk")
objLink.TargetPath = "%ProgramFiles%\Microsoft Office\Office16\OUTLOOK.EXE"
objLink.IconLocation = "%ProgramFiles%\Microsoft Office\Office16\OUTLOOK.EXE, 0"
objLink.Save
WScript.Echo "Acceso directo para Outlook creado en la barra de tareas"

Set objShell = Nothing
Set objLink = Nothing

WScript.Echo "Deshabilitando Windows Spotlight..."
reg add "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\CloudContent" /v "DisableWindowsSpotlightFeatures" /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f
WScript.Echo "Windows Spotlight deshabilitado"


WScript.Echo "Deshabilitando telemetría..."
reg add "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\DataCollection" /v "AllowTelemetry" /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f
WScript.Echo "Telemetría deshabilitada"
"

WScript.Echo "Ready papá, Press any key to exit"
WScript.StdIn.Read 1
```

Comment: Buen día, por favor oprime [edit] y agrega los errores que te aparecen tal cual para que sea más fácil revisar el problema. Saludos

Comment: Pon además un resumen del error en el título mismo, y el error con su descripción en el cuerpo de la pregunta. Lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.

Comment: A modo de comentario diré que la ida esta buena, alguna vez has probado hacerla con bats? porque eso seria super porque cualquiera lo podría editar. PD: cuando lo hagas quizás me puedas pasar el exe para probarlo. Yo hago bats para tareas comunes y por ejemplo "mato" muchos procesos innecesarios que me ayudan día a día.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.